# GMAT related problems

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any platform on SE, where one can ask questions related to reading comprehensions (from a verified source like past year question papers of GMAT) , poems, parajumbles, parasummaries, grammar related questions ?

Answer (score 2):

The SE platform is built on a question-and-answer format, so asking for opinions or links to references are unlikely to be allowed on any site on the network.